# How to view Heap and non-heap memory usage telemetry of java

Tags: java, heap-memory

How to view Heap and non-heap memory usage telemetry of java? I need to view the graphical chart. Kindly guide me

Comment: You can use bundled with jdk visualVM application or any other third party solutions out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I can use jvisualvm or jconsole. Thanks for SimY4